# Accessing multidimensional C++ std::vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

Question:

If I have a pointer to 1D std::vector I can access its content through function `at(index)` like

```
std::vector<T> *ptr_to_vec;
T vec_value = ptr_to_vec->at(index);
```

Is there a way of using this for multidimensional std::vector as well, or I am stuck with pointer dereferencing?

```
std::vector<vector<T> > *ptr_to_2Dvec;
T 2Dvec_value = (*ptr_to_2Dvec)[index1][index2];
```

I would like to avoid pointer dereferencing in the code.

Comment: so what's wrong with `ptr->at(index1)[index2]`? BTW, you **do** realize that the `->` operator also dereferences the pointer? Also, `ptr->operator[](index1)[index2]` would work too.

Comment: You have a pointer to "something". You're not getting at that "something" without dereferencing, Liking it makes no difference.

Comment: The most effective way to avoid dereferencing pointers, in my personal experience, is to not use pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to dereference the pointer to access the outer vector, just as you do with the one-dimensional vector (using `->` rather than `*`). You can use `at` rather than `operator[]` on either vector if you like.

```
ptr_to_vec->at(index1).at(index2);
```

> I would like to avoid pointer dereferencing in the code.

You can only do that by avoiding pointers. That's a good idea if you can  - using a reference, or directly accessing a variable - but there's not enough information to tell whether that's an option in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you need to use a pointer to a `vector`?  If you are just using it as a stack variable there really isn't any reason to use a pointer, and if you are passing it to a function or class you could use a reference instead (`void func(vector<vector<T> > &vec)` or `myclass(vector<vector<T> > &vec)`).  From a syntax point of view, this would mean no dereferencing.